# Best approach to slice text image into characters

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I need to process some text images, images from reCAPTCHA. I want to slice the image into pieces, each is a bounding box of one character. 
The images contain both light font color and dark font color, and all images comes with some white margin space.

For example:

[image]
[image]

I have preprocessed the images into grayscale and de-skewed them. 
How can I proceed slicing the image. 
How can I get rid of the white margin, is there a convenient way to fill the margin with similar text background color?

Comment: It won't be that easy, since they are intentionally trying to avoid it. Look at the first image "Jeggen". There is a huge noise even on the background.

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate in [signal processing stack exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @cagatayodabasi I believe the noise isn't intentional, those are from the new google's recaptcha: it is text extracted from real world picture taken from google's street view project to be deciphered by humans.

Comment: @jadsq Yeah, but they also have chance to put a quality threshold and get just the good images. In that case, OCR would work perfect. I think that this is completely intentional. The images are in their dataset, so they can easily (of course, roughly) estimate an SNR for each image.

Answer (score 1):

The given problem can be solved by using the `opencv` by finding the contours. Have a look on the `findcontours` function from the `opencv` documentation. It helped me to solve this problem. Use ranges to limit the noises that are created by contours.

```
image = cv2.cvtColor('image.jpg',cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY,1)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(image,150,255,0)
n_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```